# Simulate pressing enter key in Perl

Tags: perl, enter, keystroke, simulate

I have following perl script which saves the output from the command into a textfile

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my $cmd_backupset=`ssh user\@ip 'dsmadmc -id=username -password=passwd "q backupset"' >> output.txt`;

open CMD, "|$cmd_backupset" or die "Can not run command $!\n";
print CMD "\n";
close CMD;
```

The output of output.txt is this:

```
Text Text Text
...
more...   (<ENTER> to continue, 'C' to cancel)
```

The script is still running in the terminal and when I press enter, the output.txt file gets the extra information. However, I must press enter more than 30 times to get the complete output. Is there a way to automate the script so when the last line in output.txt is `more...`, it simulates pressing enter?

I have tried with `Expect` (couldn't get it installed) and with `echo -ne '\n'`

Comment: Try piping `yes ""` to your command to send Enters - test at the Terminal prompt with just typing it first - press Ctrl-C to abort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most interactive commands, like the one you are using, accept some flag or some command to disable pagination. Sometimes, connecting their `stdin` stream to something that is not a TTY (e.g. `/dev/null`) also works.

Just glancing over IBM `dsmadmc` docs, I see it accepts the option `-outfile=save.out`. Using it instead of standard shell redirection would probably work in your case.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of that option, it did the trick!